# Launch a simulation with input parameter in matlab from command prompt

Tags: matlab, simulink

i am fairly new to matlab so the question might be totally nonsense. i did google these stuff and just got lost.
I have given a state flow model which is simulation of two missile. one is target and another is seeker. the input to my simulation is position of target and simulation time stamp. based on the input the simulation will calculate the output (position of seeker). i have to run this simulation for every incoming target position. the questions are ::
1. How do i provide input(target position) to my simulation from my C++ application?
2. since i have to calculate seeker position for each target input, is running the simulation for one time step for every given input is the right approach?

```
Engine *ep;
ep = engOpen("");
engSetVisible(ep, true);
engEvalString(ep, "clear");
engEvalString(ep, "sim('mySimulationModel')");
for(every input of target)
{
    // How to provide input to this start of simulation
    engEvalString(ep, "set_param('mySimulationModel','SimulationCommand','start')");
    // read the required variable from workspace
}
```

Comment: usually it's not hard to translate C++ code to Matlab code. Would that be an option? (would definitely save you lots of the annoyances)

Answer (score 1):

Caveat - I'm not that familiar with the MATLAB engine, but I think something like this should work.

You might be better off wrapping up you simulation into a function. Also, note that many Simulink models are configured to read parameters from the base workspace, so you probably need [`assignin('base', ...)`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)

```
function [t, x, y] = simWrapper(param)
    assignin('base', 'myParameter', param);
    [t, x, y] = sim('mySimulationModel', [0 10]);
end
```

Note that I'm using the old [SIM](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html) syntax there.